# Applying for asylum at airport

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, airports, london

How likely is it when someone come to London and applied for asylum in airport, I was watching the uk border force tv show someone enter U.K. With passport and had some sort of visa to transit through U.K. And on flight got rid of passport and claimed asylum. Since they couldn't find any document of him and he claim his life  in danger if sent back to his country they have to let him enter uk  and go through asylum process. How likely will he be successful doing that.?

Comment: It depends on the strength of his claim, don't you think?

Comment: What do you mean by successful? Do you mean 'not immediately deported' or 'eventually allowed to settle as a refugee'?

Comment: I should think so , but I was surprised they couldnt find the trace of him where about he flew from how did he get there

Comment: Yes Dj clayworth not imidaitly deported or found which route he traveled from, I don't think they could deport him cus had no travel document or any papaers

Comment: The airline knows your citizenship and you can always be deported to that country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a travel question.

Comment: I believe you could reasonably ask this question on Expatriates.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the UK system, but I can describe the Canadian system which I believe is broadly similar.

On arrival a border officer is going to make an initial assessment of your claim. Obviously frivolous claims will be rejected. If you dump your passport on the flight this will be an immediate cause for suspicion, as they know you needed your passport to get on the flight. The airline will have a record of your passport number. If it looks like you are trying to fraudulently enter the country you may be arrested and probably deported.

Assuming your claim is not obviously invalid, you are allowed to enter the country and given a certain amount of time to explain why you need refugee protection. Then a certain amount more time to back this up and provide evidence. A decision is made by a refugee official at a formal hearing.

The likelihood of success is entirely dependent on the case you make for being in danger in your country, and the quality of evidence you can provide to back this up.